# Lightning Activity Email template with junction

Tags: lightning, email, template, activity

How do I make a template for a record's Activity > Email tab in Lightning so that the user can send the record's info (including info related by junction) to other users and to email addresses manually entered on the Bcc line?

I thought VisualForce template could do it but when I try to send to a user I get this error message: "You must send Visualforce templates to either a Contact or a Lead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this the following way:

VisualForce is no longer a valid option.
Use Process Builder to make a process called when record is updated.
Use Flow Builder to make a flow that is called from the above process.

In the flow:
Get the list of relations in a collection
Loop over the relations
  For each relation, get the linked object
  Insert text based on the linked object, can use text template or formula.
Finally save the object.

The attached actually shows 3 loops because I pick up 3 different junctions.

I then insert this as a merge field in a Lightning template.

[image: Flow illustration]